# Unsuccessful upgrade from 20.04 to 21.10

Tags: upgrade, multiple-monitors, usb-c

I have just upgraded from 20.04 to 21.10. It uninstalled a few programs (eg. Tex Maker), a few packages previously installed but what is the most annoying my 3rd monitor stopped working. I have one monitor added through HDMI, and another one via HDMI to QGeeM and that to USB-c. The first one works, and the second one stopped. It worked fine during the upgrade, then I was asked to reboot the system, I agreed and it stopped working at that moment. What should I do?

Edit: `ubuntu-drivers devices` does not produce any output and I have nothing in additional drivers in `software and updates`.

I feel like luck of some drivers might be a problem?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, stupid error, I used `do-release-upgrade` and upgraded to 21.10 of course, not 22.04.

Comment: do-release-upgrade only supports upgrading from 20.04 to 22,04 (LTS to LTS) or 20.04 to 20.10 which is EOL and therefor not on-topic here, Please describe procedure followed.

Answer (score 0):

I think upgrading from 20.04 to 21.10 is not a wise decision. you may want to upgrade direectly to 22.04 which is newest ubuntu LTS version using following command or using Software and Updates graphical tool.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -c -d
```

Answer (score -1):

Re-installing display link drivers fixed it.

Comment: Your question title is very misleading. The upgrade worked.

Comment: Bearing in mind how many packages and programs it has been uninstalled during the upgrade and how it broke my venvs - I don't think I can say it worked CORRECTLY.